# dusk test about continuity click(double click) without waiting backend process

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-dusk

I am testing the following due with laravel dusk.
Vue component purpose is disable continuity click by user to avoid registering duplicate data.
The test I want to implement is fast continuity click by user.

But after

```
$browser->assertSourceHas($buttonEnableSource)
->click('@submit-button-component')
```

Test will wait for browser process.
So if I write down the following, it will make error that has no applicable Vue.

```
$browser->assertSourceHas($buttonEnableSource)
->click('@submit-button-component')
->click('@submit-button-component')
```

Is there a way to implement fast continuity click by user with dusk?

The following is the source code.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" class="button_orange button_big" :value="value" v-show="!isSubmitting" @click="startSubmit">
    <div class="button_white button_big" v-show="isSubmitting">{{ value }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        isSubmitting: false,
      };
    },
    props: {
      value: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
      },
    },
    methods: {
      startSubmit() {
        this.isSubmitting = true;
      },
    },
  };
</script>


public function testRegisterDoubleClickNoDuplication()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $buttonValue = __('common.register');
        $buttonEnableSource = "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"button_orange button_big\" value=\"{$buttonValue}\" />";
        $browser->visit(route('staffs.create'))
                ->assertSourceHas($buttonEnableSource)
                ->click('@submit-button-component')
                ->assertSourceMissing($buttonEnableSource)
                ->assertSee('スタッフ詳細');
    });
}
```